# Contact Microsoft if aka.ms does not work

Tags: visual-studio, chocolatey

We are experiencing failures when running Chocolatey scripts to install Visual Studio Community (2017, 2019, 2022) on our build machines.

We experience the following errors:

```
ERROR: The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/channel'. Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
The install of visualstudio2019community was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019community\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.

Failures
 - visualstudio2019community (exited 404) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019community
\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

However I don't know how to contact Microsoft to escalate the fact that aka.ms is down for Visual Studio downloads.

I've contacted the Chocolatey Team via [discord](https://discord.com/channels/778552361454141460/897088817293574154) and they cannot do anything about it.

Comment: Maybe try https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8. Hope you can get a result there. This question will likely be closed though.

Comment: thanks a lot, I realize SO isn't the place to get an answer, I need some hint from the community because Google really doesn't help and neither do Microsoft's websites (including the https://my.visualstudio.com which has very poor experience for getting help)

Answer (score 0):

Use https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com to report.

Enter Visual Studio, "Report a problem" and this will redirect to developer community.